# Getting variables from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two functions:

```
function ajaxtakesource4(callback){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }   
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange =function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 &&ajaxRequest.status==200){
            var sourcetest = ajaxRequest.responseText;  
            callback(sourcetest);
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "takesource4.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

The second one, called `ajaxtakesource3` is similar to `ajaxtakesource4`.
Then i have

```
function run() {
    var somous4 , somous3 ;
    ajaxtakesource4(function(sourcetest){   
       var  somous4=sourcetest;
    });
     ajaxtakesource3(function(sourcetest){   
       var  somous3=sourcetest;
    });
    var result= soumous3+somous4;
    alert (result);
}
```

I call the above the function on button click:

```
<div id="run">
    <button id="button_run" class="button" onclick="run()">Run</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that i can use the variable `somous4` only in the function `ajaxtakesource4` and the same the `somous3` variable.
I would like to use them in run function.

Comment: `var  somous3` inside `function-block` will be local but this is not primary the issue..Basically, You need to test whether all the callbacks are invoked and then do the `sum`

Comment: i found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call and especially the answer of If you're not using jQuery in your code, this answer is for you - restructured code BUT there is not the answer in my question. So please when duplicate a question please modify the problem of the user or make it clear if there is the answer in this topic and where.

Comment: The highest rated answer, which is the accepted answer, which has the accepted bounty on it answers this. It uses jQuery in the examples but the principles are the same.

Comment: Obviously my question is without using Jquery so i dont think that your answer excuse the duplication.

Comment: I would also like to see the answer in pure Javascript.

Comment: you haev right about the second comment and especially the paragraph Restructure code if you saw it and if you saw my code i dont have something similar to function myHandler(result)
He wrote in this function that  code that depends on `result and then he calls the function. When i tried to modify the run function it doesnt work.